# where to write command in a linux server

Tags: linux, terminal, command-line-interface

With the possibility of being down-voted, I find no other way but ask here where I am supposed to write command in online Linux server. I googled but cannot find any answer perhaps because of my ignorance in Linux environment.

Let me explain more : In the case of the Windows 7 environment I am working in, I can find the command prompt  by  typing  `cmd` in the 'search programs and files'  search bar. There is such a way if I am running Linux in my desktop. But

when the online server is a Linux one, where can I get such a terminal like thing to write commands for `chmod` or installing any script without having the full access to the server?

Comment: Try [SSH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell), If you are on Windows try [mRemoteNG](http://www.mremoteng.org/).

Comment: @yegorich,  Again you link SSH  to wikipedia without mentioning the way to use it.

Comment: See this [video tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9CZphjhQxIQ).

Comment: @yegorich, let me see the video. until I see the video, such instructions are galore in net without telling any noob that is the tool to do this. .

Comment: really amazed to see the down vote. 'Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming.'- this is what I got from SO. I asked about a toll that is very much related with programming

Answer (score 3):

The most common way to access a command line interface on a remote Linux server is by way of SSH.  PuTTY is a widely used SSH client.  See http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/ for more info.

Comment: I knew about Putty. Is that the thing to work for  such purpose ?! And have  got one down vote already. Did not find ( myself) anyplace in net to tell that in words.

Comment: @IstiaqueAhmed Yes, connecting from Windows, PuTTY is probably the simplest (free) way to connect to a linux server. It uses SSH as a protocol which makes the connection secure, but makes the setup of the connection fairly simple.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your environment

- If it is only text-based, then you may try key combinations Ctr+Alt+F1 , Ctr+Alt+F2 etc. and then login
- If you are logged in in side a Graphical Desktop, then it could be a Gnome or KDE or any other desktop. Try Ctrl+F2 and then type any of the following:

  - xterm
  - gnome-terminal
  - konsole
- If you have only remote access via SSH, then you can login remotely as well.

Any other options?

Comment: Looking at the crying basic need in the question , do you really think this answer will come to any use ?

Comment: You must provide some more details, like what have you tried so far, where have you reached, any screen-shots etc.

Comment: ,I browsed and browsed, got the SSH stuffs but could not find how to execute the commands.

Comment: As mentioned by @mti2935 , download putty.exe and use it to connect to your linux server. However, the server must have SSH server running.